# Excecute program on Windows Bash?

Tags: linux, bash, assembly, windows-10

I have write a little .s program witch have to print a little string on the monitor. 
Then I opened the linux bash on windows 10 and done:

```
as -o file.o file.s
ld -o file file.o
./file
```

but it doesn't print anything
Why? I tried the same code on a linux virtual machine and it works

The file it is a simple "hello world" for learn Assembly at school

```
.section .data

hello:
    .ascii "Hello, World!\n"

hello_len:
    .long . - hello


.section .text
    .global _start

_start:

    movl $4, %eax
    movl $1, %ebx
    leal hello, %ecx
    movl hello_len, %edx
    int $0x80
    movl $1, %eax
    xor %ebx, %ebx
    int $0x80
```

Comment: do you get an error message ? Did you compile the object files on your linux vm or on your wsl ?

Comment: Linux code won't work in windows. Accessing the operating system to print stuff differs.

Comment: I compile the object files both in linux vm and in windows and it dosn't give any error. When i execute in linux I can see the string in the terminal, but in windows it doesn't print; it return in the file path

Comment: @Jester OP is using bash on windows, so linux code should run as expected

Comment: Did you make your file executable with `chmod +x file` ?

Comment: @Aserre nope! Now I try on windows..

Comment: @Aserre it doens't work

Comment: Could you [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/42855363/edit) your question and add the content of your `file.s` so we can try to reproduce your issue ?

Comment: @DarkerD You need to assemble and link your program as a 32 bit program. For the assembler, pass `--32`, for the linker, pass `-m elf_i386`.

Comment: @fuz Now, when do "./file" it gives me this error: "bash: ./hw: cannot execute binary file: Formato eseguibile non valido"  (hw is the real name of my file!)

Comment: @DarkerD Seems like WSL (Windows Subsystem for Linux) doesn't support 32 bit binaries. You can either use an actual Linux system or learn how to write 64 bit binaries, I guess.

Comment: @fuz yup, you are right. Issue is currently tracked [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/BashOnWindows/issues/390).

Comment: Thank you all! For my little example.. Would be hard make it 64-bit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As WSL is currently in beta, some features are not functionnal yet. Running 32 bits ELF binaries is part of the missing features (the issue is logged on WSL [github](https://github.com/Microsoft/BashOnWindows/issues/390) and [uservoice](https://wpdev.uservoice.com/forums/266908-command-prompt-console-bash-on-ubuntu-on-windo/suggestions/13377507-please-add-32-bit-elf-support-to-the-kernel)).

Currently, to do what you want, your can either wait until the devs publish this feature or redo your program using the `x86_64` instruction set that can be found [here](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-sdm).